# Is is possible to copy binary data containing a NUL character to the X clipboard?

Tags: linux, xorg, clipboard

If I do either of:

```
printf 'a\0b' | xsel
printf 'a\0b' | xsel -b
printf 'a\0b' | xclip
printf 'a\0b' | xclip -selection c
```

and then paste from the corresponding selection (PRIMARY or CLIPBOARD) on either of:

- browser textareas
- text editors
- pipe like in `xsel | hexdump`

only `a` gets output.

So, is it possible to store binary data on the clipboard and then paste it later? How?

I originally wanted to do this to save images to the clipboard, which would also solve:

- [Copy image from command-line to clipboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30093/copy-image-from-command-line-to-clipboard)
- [How to copy a picture to clipboard from command line in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/301851/how-to-copy-a-picture-to-clipboard-from-command-line-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard *does* contain the full string:

```
$ printf 'a\0b' | hexdump -c
0000000   a  \0   b                                                    
0000003
$ printf 'a\0b' | xclip && xclip -out | hexdump -c
0000000   a  \0   b                                                    
0000003
```

So `xclip -out` *will* print the input verbatim, NUL characters and all. Most likely the desktop clipboard integration stops output at NUL characters. One obvious problem with pasting NUL characters is that it wouldn't be visible to the user, and as such would likely cause unexpected behaviour. Not to mention that even [popular software can fail to handle NUL characters properly](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/297.html).

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't tried pipes with input and output to `xclip`: it fails if either of input or output is on `xsel`. But what kind of bug does this avoid? Feels a bit like an unnecessary restriction.